# Username and Password Failing to load properly in website

Tags: python

I have created a script that takes two text files "username.txt" and "password.txt". My script try's to log in with the given data provided in the 2 text files.I have I have user1@mymail.com to user10@mymail.com in the username.txt file and password1 to password10 in the password.txt. If it succeeds to log in it ought to give me a HTTP request code 200, if unsuccessful it should give me a code 400. My code is running the first line only and doesn't run the rest. How can I fix this issue. Here is my code.

```
import urllib, urllib2

user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')
pa = ''.join(password)

for users in user:
    login_data = pa + users
    base_url = 'http://mymail.com'       
# login action we want to post data to  
response = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)     
login_action = '/auth/login'   
login_action = base_url + login_action
response = urllib2.urlopen(login_action, login_data)
response.read()
print response.headers
print response.getcode()
```

Here is my output when I run the script. Mark I have set the users that are supposed to fail but I am getting a code 200.

```
Date: Mon, 29 Jul 2013 14:54:59 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=o3jlu86jgs7uj24fod107aps26; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

200
```

Comment: Did you try to log in with fixed `user` and `password` values?

Comment: what does `running the first line only mean`? Is there an error? If so could you post it with fullt raceback?

Comment: For a start, you could try *reading* the files `user = open ('users.txt' , 'r').readlines()`

Comment: On a sidenote - I'd hope the server would give you a 403...

Comment: I see an inconsistency in your spelling of 'response'

Comment: You could not have spaces separating `open` and `(`. Additionally, I think the last 7 lines should probably be indented, no?

Comment: Only just noticed the address you've put - you're trying to connect to gmail with a list of usernames and passwords... This seems remarkably suspicious to me... Besides - for genuine purposes - why not just use IMAP ?

Comment: @JonClements Under what circumstances will you attempt to login to multiple accounts with a list of usernames and passwords that isn't nefarious. This is very suspicious, especially looking at his submission history, and should be flagged.

Comment: We have an in house mailing software and I am creating a script to make sure we don't use some of the common passwords out there. So I have a list of week passwords that are commonly used. I need to flag this accounts in the production environment to change the passwords for security reasons

Comment: You shouldn't try to crack the user's password to deal with that. Implement a filter on the server side to prevent further use of these "common passwords", and if you're concerned about existing passwords, forcing a global password reset may be in order. A less egregious way of limiting it to users who actually have "common" passwords would be to detect it server-side as they log in, and force a reset after authentication succeeds with one of these passwords.

Comment: `for users in user` - this is a new and innovative way to make your code confusing.

Comment: @MunduwaNgai your question should be in programmers.stackexchange.com and you should be asking how to implement strong-password checking for user registration rather than sticking with this very poor solution and trying to make it work. sometimes all you need to do is step back and re-think the problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All I had to do was make sure that my loop goes back to the beginning of the nested loop and use the .seek functionality and it loads all passwords and try's them out.

```
import urllib, urllib2

user = open ('users.txt' , 'r')
password = open ('password.txt' , 'r')

for users in user:
    password.seek(0)
    for pass_list in password:
        login_data = users + '\n' + pass_list
        print login_data

base_url = 'http://my-site.com'       
#login action we want to post data to  
response = urllib2.urlopen(base_url)     
login_action = '/auth/login'   
login_action = base_url + login_action
response = urllib2.urlopen(login_action, login_data)
response.read()
print response.headers
print response.getcode()
```